Apply in Automapper a Condition over Multiple Map Expressions Without Repetition
I need to apply the following condition ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)) over multiple map expressions.
My objective is to have an object overriding the contents of another object using mapper but only where the value is not null, like this var object = mapper.Map(newData, existingData);.
My current code looks like this but with more map expressions:
public class MappingConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMaps()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<PermissaoEntity, PermissaoVO>().ReverseMap()
            .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
            config.CreateMap<SystemCategoria, CategoriaVO>().ReverseMap()
            .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
        });
    }
}

It works but needs lots of copying and pasting.

Try ForAllMaps.

    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMaps() {
    return new MapperConfiguration(config => {
        config.CreateMap<PermissaoEntity, PermissaoVO>().ReverseMap();
        config.CreateMap<SystemCategoria, CategoriaVO>().ReverseMap();

        config.Internal().ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) =>
            mappingExpression.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))
        );
    });

ForAllMaps() was the answer I was looking for but this answer is also a good one.

This definition is quite verbose. You can extract it into extension method:

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IMapperConfigurationExpression CustomCreateMap<T1, T2>(
        this IMapperConfigurationExpression expression)
    {
        expression.CreateMap<T1, T2>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));

        // Return the expression to allow chaining method calls.
        return expression;
    }
}

And then your implementation would simplify a little:
expression
    .CustomCreateMap<PermissaoEntity, PermissaoVO>()
    .CustomCreateMap<SystemCategoria, CategoriaVO>();

UPDATE
To simplify things, if you would like to go that way, you could add utility interface:
public interface IEntityWithVo<T>;

and another version of extension method:
public static void CustomCreateMap(
    this IMapperConfigurationExpression expression,
    Type source,
    Type destination)
{
    expression.CreateMap(source, destination)
        .ReverseMap()
        .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
}

And then you could use such code to scan assembly for all types implementing interface IEntityWithVo and automatically register it:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(expression =>
{
    var entitiesWithVos = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Select(x => (
            Entity: x, 
            Interface: x.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithVo<>))))
        .Where(x => x.Interface != default(Type))
        .ToArray();

    Array.ForEach(entitiesWithVos, x =>
    {
        expression.CustomCreateMap(
            x.Entity,
            x.Interface.GetGenericArguments()[0]); 
    });
});

Now, you can just "relate" classes with the interface, and they will be automatically registered in AutoMapper.
